# How to insert the next highest number

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table with an id, tableid, and seqnum. Here is the table structure:

```
create table ztables
(
   id serial primary key,
   tableid integer,
   seqnum integer
)
```

and sample data

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | tableid | seqnum|
+----+---------+-------+
| 1  | 5       | 1     |
+----+---------+-------+
| 2  | 5       | 2     |
+----+---------+-------+
| 3  | 5       | 3     |
+----+---------+-------+
| 4  | 5       | 9     |
+----+---------+-------+
| 5  | 6       | 1     |
+----+---------+-------+
| 6  | 7       | 1     |
+----+---------+-------+
| 7  | 7       | 2     |
+----+---------+-------+
| 8  | 7       | 3     |
+----+---------+-------+
```

Lets take tableid 5 as an example. You can see the sequence number increases similar to a database sequence. But it should not increase for the whole table. I only want it to increase per tableid. So, if another record with tableid 5 is inserted the seqnum will be 10. If a record with tableid 7 is inserted the seqnum will be 4. What is the right way to do something like this. I need to account for concurrency issues as well.

Comment: This has been asked many times ... I suggest searching the [tag:postgresql] tag history for things along the lines of category sequence or sub-sequence, etc.

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672629/postgresql-company-id-based-sequence

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that helps you or gives you at least an idea for a solution:

```
insert into ztables (
  id,
  tableid,
  seqnum
)
select ? as id,
       tableid,
       max(seqnum) + 1 as seqnum
  from ztables 
 where tableid = ?
 group 
    by tableid
 union
select ? as id,
       ? as tableid,
       1 as seqnum
  from ztables
 order
    by 3 desc
 limit 1;
```

The question marks has to be replaced by constant values.

Comment: This will fail under concurrency unless you `LOCK TABLE ztables IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` or take some appropriate row lock.