# how to insert a record to keep track of states according to country ( i think that is partition sequence)?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

how I can follow the order of a column according to their foreign key?

for example: i have two tables (Country and State)

country(id, country)
state(id_country, id_state, state) this is where i have the problem...

I want to keep the order by country with a sequence

1 | 1 | first state in the country one 
1 | 2 | second state in the country one 
1 | 3 | third state in the country one 
2 | 1 | first state in the country two

this is possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the order"?  Usually, this kind of result is achieved by querying your database, and specifying an `ORDER BY` clause to direct the sorting order of the result set.  In your example, the tables would be `JOIN`d together in the query before sorting.  Sorting first by country, then by state would achieve the output you desire.

Comment: Modify the question so that it was obvious what exactly you need to achieve.

Comment: I looked in other questions .. but I need to know how to do the insert to follow the counting of states according to country? I got this, but no solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591298/how-to-create-a-postgresql-partitioned-sequence?rq=1

Comment: Did you see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672629/postgresql-company-id-based-sequence ? There is a solution there, although it could have concurrency issues.

Comment: It does not matter the order you use to insert the rows. There is no guarantee they will be retrieved in that order unless you use the `order by` clause.

Comment: actually interest me for to insert regardless of the order that will,  after i have a query and filter