# How to create a PostgreSQL partitioned sequence for points generated from polygon vertices?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

My question is similar to this question  [How to create a PostgreSQL partitioned sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591298/how-to-create-a-postgresql-partitioned-sequence)

In My case am converting polygon vertex to points using this code

```
SELECT geom, gid, path,nextval('seq_oid1') as seq_id,
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY gid ORDER BY gid) AS pos
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (geom) geom, path, gid
FROM (
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom, (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path, gid
FROM edge_snapping.polygon1
) f
ORDER BY geom, path, gid
) f
ORDER BY gid, path;
```

But this code generates sequence id for all the vertices regardless of polygon id.

I want to index the points based on partitioned by polygon id, and the points generated from each polygons should start with sequence id  with 1. I appreciate any help. As i am not sure what to do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT geom, gid, path,nextval('seq_oid1') as seq_id,
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY gid ORDER BY gid) AS pos
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (geom) geom, path, gid
FROM (
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom, (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path, gid
FROM edge_snapping.polygon1
) f
ORDER BY geom, path, gid
) f
WHERE pos = 1 ORDER BY gid, path;
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "pos" does not exist , It gives an error like this.

Comment: SELECT * FROM
(SELECT geom, gid, path,nextval('seq_oid1') as seq_id,
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY gid ORDER BY gid) AS pos
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (geom) geom, path, gid
FROM (
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom, (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path, gid
FROM edge_snapping.polygon1
) f
ORDER BY geom, path, gid
) f
ORDER BY gid, path
) f3
WHERE pos = 1